# Getting javadoc for Google Wave robot programming in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, google-wave

Does anyone know how I can get the helpful Eclipse popups with javadoc when programming for the Google Wave Robots API? I have access to the JAR-file, the HTML Javadoc, as well as the source files from [here](http://code.google.com/p/wave-robot-java-client/downloads/list)

How do I set up eclipse so I get javadoc integrated? I have tried adding the source files, but things just get "messy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean messy?

I have found that attaching source will give you the tooltip popups when you hover over items. It also allows you to browse the source, and you'll get line numbers in your stack traces.

To do it find the JAR in the Referenced Libraries node of the package explorer, right click, Properties > Java Source Attachment, then enter the path to the source.

Comment: That solved it! Thanks! I just tried dragging the source files into eclipse, that was what created the mess :P